# vba: convert range into formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to define the range of values for a chart.

Starting with the name, I can define it using

```
.SeriesCollection(count).name = "=Spektren!$B$1"
```

but "B" is actually a parameter which I save in `col`, therefore I want to address this with Cells. However

```
 Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col)
 Sheets("Spektren").Range(Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col), Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col))
```

both insert the value of the cell, not its Formular. Even if I try

```
Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col).Formular
```

this does not change. Even worse, if I do that for the values the data can not be displayed anymore.

So this leave the basic question how to convert a well known Range into a valid Excel Cell Formula.

Answer (score 0):

if the value of `col` is `B` then this should work:

```
Sheets("Spektren").Range(col & "1").Formular
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to find, but finally got it (using `.Address`):

```
Sheets("Spektren").Range(Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col), Sheets("Spektren").Cells(1, col)).Address
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted the contents of the range.